# How to get query firestore with geofirestore and get documents in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I tried the code below to fetch the location data filtered by nearby certain location.
but I don't know how to get documents.

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let geoFirestoreRef = db.collection("spot")
        let geoFirestore = GeoFirestore(collectionRef: geoFirestoreRef)
        
        // Query using CLLocation
        let center = CLLocation(latitude: 35.681236, longitude: 139.767125)
        // Query locations at [37.7832889, -122.4056973] with a radius of 100km
        var circleQuery = geoFirestore.query(withCenter: center, radius: 100.0)

        let _ = circleQuery.observe(.documentEntered, with: { (key, location) in
            geoFirestoreRef.document(key!).getDocument  { (document, error) in
                           if let document = document, document.exists {
                               print(document)
                           } else {
                               print("Document does not exist.")
                           }
                       }
            print("The document with documentID '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'")
        })
```

```
circleQuery
```

This variable just return GFSCircleQuery object.
I don't know how to fetch the actual documents filtered by query.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a query in Firebase, you can call .getDocuments or similar. Firebase has really detailed documentation online that you should probably start with. https://firebase.google.com/docs

Comment: I've read a geofirestore document and I could solve this problem.
Thank you.